# Not adhering to All files access permission policy

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-permissions, android-11

I am using Room database with external storage db. In android 11 database can't read by programmatic, so i added below permission in my manifest file and get permission by user.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
```

Permission code for android 11

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

It working fine. After upload the apk to playstore they reject the app for the reason of

> Not adhering to All files access permission policy

How i can solve this

Comment: If Google rejects it, there is nothing you can do about it. `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is intended for file explorer applications. Even if you have a file explorer application, it doesn't mean that your application will be accepted.

Comment: Hi guys, I am using public directory to store my database it will work perfect in android 11

Comment: omg... that's right. I also encountered the similar case.
it appears that my app's core feature requires access to only Media Files or does not need access to any Files (which is manage external permission is being rejected).